# Mixed Effects Ordinal Logistic Regression with Lasso

Tags: r, mixed-model, feature-selection, lasso, ordered-logit

I have data where the outcome is ordinal (1-5) scale. I have about 500k observations that are nested into groups. The predictors are age, gender, job, and 200-300 questions (yes/no/no response).

I'd like to use the LASSO to fit the following model

```
ord.resp ~ (1|group) + age*gender + job + 
           quest1*age*gender+quest1*job+
           ...
           quest200*age*gender+quest200*job
```

After some research, it looks like glmmLasso was my best bet because glmnetcr does not allow for random intercepts.

I wrote a for loop to specify the model above, without the random intercept

```
model.dat<-glmmLasso(formula, rnd = list(group=~1), 
                data = model.dat,
                family = cumulative(),lambda=10)
```

Note the package details suggest using as.factor(), but I have interactions. I attempted to simply put the interactions in the as.factor() call as suggested on [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910042/glmmlasso-warning-messages); however this yields a parsing error (I think the formula is too many characters long.)

```
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
```

With the interactions (no as.factor), the model won't attempt to run -- I get the following error:

```
Error in blockstand(X, ipen.which, inotpen.which) : 
  Block belonging to columns 66, 1135 has not full rank! 
In addition: Warning message:
In split.default((1:ncol(X))[-inotpen.which], ipen) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

Without the interactions, it pops an error that it needs 20gb of memory.

The following model DOES fit in glmnetcr

```
ord.resp ~ age*gender + job + 
           quest1*age*gender+quest1*job+
           ...
           quest200*age*gender+quest200*job
```

using

```
modframe<-model.frame(formula,data = model.dat)
x<-model.matrix(formula,modframe)
y<-ordered(model.dat$ord.resp)        
mod<-glmnetcr(x=x,y=y,exclude=c())
```

Questions:

- Is it possible to ask which features are causing the issues with glmmLasso?
- Is it possible to simply plug-in model matrices into glmmLasso, like glmnetcr?
- Is there another package that I'm missing that might work better?